# I am facing issue of volumetric effect in blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, volumetrics

Volumetric light not working in render evee and cycles but fog is visible in viewport. When i render it solid color appear see images[viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByuHP.jpg)

[image: render]

[image]

Comment: Maybe look in to compositing editor, there might be something wrong there.

Comment: Hello :). The plane with your particle system is disabled in render (check the camera icon).